# GitLab deploy to server without SSH

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I started learning GitLab CI, so far don't understand GitLab runner concept:

1. There is a video when a guy installs gitlab-runner on the "prod" server then register it with a token from GitLab, and that's it. His .gitlab-ci.yml is executed on the server via installed and registered runner. Why there is no SSH?
2. If we connect via SSH and execute deploy commands, why do we need to install gitlab-runner if we can use a shared one?

Comment: `There is a video` What video? Why not post a link to it? Or did you record it? `Why there is no SSH?` Ask the guy from the video. What other answer do you expect? `If we connect via SSH` where? What for? `execute deploy commands` what commands exactly? What are "deploy commands"? `why do we need to install gitlab-runner if we can use a shared one?` You do not _need_ to install, you _can_ install a gitlab-runner when you do not want to use the shared one. For example your projects needs more time that is available for free on gitlab.com platform, so you setup your own server.

Comment: @KamilCuk you have more questions than me =) Scripts and video are irrelevant, the question is general, if you don't know the answer please don't confuse other users =)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV0845KmsNI&t=677s here is a video

Comment: What @KamilCuk is saying is that we need more details (you can edit your Question to add them) in order to help answer your question. However, I recommend you start with the official documentation and videos they provide: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/, then if you have specific questions about what they say, the Stack Overflow community can probably answer them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It may seem odd to use SSH to run these commands on your server, considering the GitLab runner that executes the commands is the exact same server. Yet it is required, because the runner executes the commands in a Docker container, thus you would deploy inside the container instead of the server if you’d execute the commands without the use of SSH. One could argue that instead of using Docker as a runner executor, you could use the shell executor to run the commands on the host itself. But, that would create a constraint to your pipeline, namely that the runner has to be the same server as the one you want to deploy to. This is not a sustainable and extensible solution because one day you may want to migrate the application to a different server or use a different runner server. In any case it makes sense to use SSH to execute the deployment commands, may it be for technical or migration-related reasons." (с) Mike Nöthiger